# How to display boolean value(tinyInt 1) in Form Select so that it's value is autoselected in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have `tinyint(1)` column named status in my mysql table. I am displaying this field in Form as select input. My problem is form select value is not autoselected , first option is always selected ,however if i use checkbox instead of select input , value is correctly autoselected. How can i make value autoselected in select input for boolean column in cakephp3? Below are the codes i tried which doesn't work.

```
<?php
     echo $this->Form->select('status', 
                 [1 => __('Active'), 0 => __('Inactive')], 
                 ['class' => 'form-control input-medium']
                 );
   ?>
 <?php
     echo $this->Form->select('status', 
                 [true => __('Active'), false => __('Inactive')], 
                 ['class' => 'form-control input-medium']
                 );
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
 $this->Form->input('status', [
     'options' => [
          0 => __('Inactive')
          1 => __('Active')
      ],
      'class' => 'form-control input-medium'
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, awkward behavior when i keep 0 => __('Inactive') before  1 => __('Active') then it works but  i wanted  1 => __('Active') as default selected , i fixed it by passing 'default' => 1

Comment: i don't know how it is supposed to work but if i changed length of column higher than 1 for eg tinyint(2) then  above code works but it wasn't working for bolean column where cakephp returns values as true or false.

Comment: I don't understand: you told it was working. Anyway if you want to set a default value then one of the methods is setting 'default' => 1.